# why AsNoTracking() in Entity Framework decrease my performance?

Tags: performance, entity-framework

I use mvc5 and Entity Framework 6.i use AsNoTracking() to Improvement my performance but this decrease my speed.in my case without AsNoTracking() speed is around 3s but with AsNoTracking() speed is around 14s.also for more test i set AutoDetectChangesEnabled to false but this also can not help me to increase speed.

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled =false;
db.Employees.AsNoTracking().Include(e => e.Terminal).Where(-----).toList();
```

Comment: Please post your code. I suspect you may be testing a cold (i.e. non-cached) query versus a hot (cached) query.

Answer (score 0):

When chaining the `AsNoTracking` method to your query, the objects resulting from that query are not tracked in.

As you are not caching the results of a query, each time you execute the query Entity Framework will need to materialize the query result. Normally, with change tracking enabled, Entity Framework will not need to re-materialize a query result if it is already cached in the context object.

the context object includes the `Terminal` because your query explicitly included these. And then casting to List, this make your query more worst.

Comment: i removed Include(e => e.Terminal) and for easier test purpose just i have this code : db.Employees.AsNoTracking().toList(); but performance is not acceptable yet. i think AsNoTracking() in this sample should improve the performance but this isn't happen

Comment: Well then, i think the bottleneck is not on AsNoTracking(). Do you have contains on where clause?